# Action after progress bar loads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, progress-bar, action

my progress bar is coded this way:

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIProgressView *wait_progress;
    double wait_time;
    NSTimer *wait_timer;

}
-(void) increase_waiting_time;
```

.m file

```
-(void) increase_waiting_time {
    wait_time = wait_time + 0.01;
    wait_progress.progress = wait_time;
}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    wait_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(increase_waiting_time) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

How is it possible to do some action immediately after progress bar loads (that means wait_time will equals 1)?

Comment: Add an `if` statement in `increase_waiting_time`?

Comment: don't really work that way. `if (wait_time == 1) {
        button.enabled = YES;
        button.alpha = 1;
    }`
tried this and nothing happens

Comment: Testing for equality on a double is likely to cause issues. Use `>=` instead (or specify a range around `1` that is valid).

Comment: That's great thank you! you could add this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `if` statement will do the job. I guess you're falling foul of float number comparisons (testing for equality) which are problematic. Have a google on the subject. There are also answers on SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008649/comparing-floating-point-numbers-in-c)).

Basically, don't check for equality - it won't work. Instead, decide how accurate the comparison needs to be and test `<=` and `>=` to verify that the value is in that range. For you it may be good enough to simply use `>= 1`.