# How to compare float variable with double in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, compare

```
float num1 = 1;

if (num1 == 1)
{
     printf("Yes, it is equal!!\n");
}
else
{
     printf("No, it is not equal\n");
}
```

output -->  Yes, it is equal!

whereas

```
float num1 = 1.2;

if (num1 == 1.2)
{
    printf("Yes, it is equal!!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("No, it is not equal\n");
}
```

output -->  No, it is not equal

but why? 
Please explain in detail.

Comment: What is the type of f, and what is the type of 1.2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing floating point numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008649/comparing-floating-point-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

In spite of your title, there is no comparison with any `int` value.

`num == 1.2` compares the `float` value in `num` with the `double` value of `1.2`.

When `1.2` is converted to `double` in your C implementation, it is converted to the nearest representable value. Since your C implementation uses a binary-based system for floating-point, it cannot exactly represent 1.2, and there is a small error in the conversion.

In `float num1 = 1.2;`, the `double` value resulting from `1.2` is converted again, this time to `float`. Since `float` has less precision than `double`, there is even more error. The result is that the `float` `num1` is not equal to the double `1.2`.

Thus, the comparison `num1 == 1.2` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3):

Be very careful in exact comparison of float numbers. No all values can be presented as float exactly, because not all values can be presented as finite sum of components being power (positive or negative) of 2. The same problem is about double.

There is no good and universal solution for your problem, it strongly depends to kind of possible values, expected accuracy etc.

Probably you should move into integer values, for example by multyplying your floats by some power of 10, then convert (round) to int, and - finally - compare.